# Conditionally updating cells in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table of quarterly observations that I want to relate to the medicaid expansion. To do this, I want a variable in my data.table (`expanded_medicaid`) that is 1 if the state expanded it, and 0 if it didn't. I have another data.table with the date of the expansions.

So, for example, my main data.table is like:

```
state_name  qtr     ...data columns
Alabama     2008 Q1  
Alabama     2008 Q2
...
Alaska      2008 Q1
Alaska      2008 Q2
... etc
```

and another data table has the expansion dates

```
state_name    qtr
Alaska        2015 Q1
Arizona       2014 Q1
Arkansas      2014 Q1
... etc
```

Is there a neat way I can create a column `expanded_medicaid` that is 1 if qtr is >= to that state's qtr in the second data.table? (This seems like it might be a job for `sapply`, but I've never properly understood how `sapply` works.)

EDIT: ideal result is for the main table to look like this:

```
state_name   qtr      expanded_medicaid   ...data columns
...
Alaska       2013 Q3  0
Alaska       2013 Q4  0
Alaska       2014 Q1  0
Alaska       2014 Q2  0
Alaska       2014 Q3  0
Alaska       2014 Q4  0
Alaska       2015 Q1  1
Alaska       2015 Q2  1
...
Arizona      2013 Q3  0
Arizona      2013 Q4  0
Arizona      2014 Q1  1
Arizona      2014 Q2  1
Arizona      2014 Q3  1
Arizona      2014 Q4  1
Arizona      2015 Q1  1
Arizona      2015 Q2  1
...
```

Comment: please provide some example data for the two tables.  Expected result would also be useful.  NB use `dput` - the format you have now is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `data.table` with `zoo`'s `as.yearqtr()` function to compare quarters

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.table(state_name = c('Alabama', 'Arizona', 'Arkanas'),
                  qtr = c('2008 Q1', '2009 Q2', '2009 Q3'))

df2 <- data.table(state_name = c('Alabama', 'Arizona', 'Arkanas'),
                  qtr = c('2007 Q1', '2012 Q2', '2009 Q3'))

df1[, qtr := as.yearqtr(qtr, format = "%Y Q%q")]
df2[, qtr := as.yearqtr(qtr, format = "%Y Q%q")]

df1[df2, on = .(state_name), expanded_medicaid := as.integer(qtr >= i.qtr)]

#   state_name     qtr expanded_medicaid
#1:    Alabama 2008 Q1                 1
#2:    Arizona 2009 Q2                 0
#3:    Arkanas 2009 Q3                 1
```

Comment: Perfect. I had no idea data.table could do joins like this!